# Converting a frozen production symfony project back to development project

Tags: php, symfony1

I need some advice on going about converting a production version of a symfony project which is in frozen state back to a development state so I can work on the project locally. I need to do this because I'm having to download the latest working copy from the server down onto my personal macbook so that I can work on some files over this evening and the SVN is currently not to the latest revision and I don't have the latest copy on here!

Thanks in advance to all who help.

Answer (score 1):

presumly ./symfony project:unfreeze doesn't help? I've not used freeze, so not fully familiar with what it does.